# Is it common / advisable to add my personal web site to my curriculum vitae?

Tags: cv

Generally one puts more things about itself than s/he puts in his/her CV, and I think a CV should standalone and be a guide for someone who is trying to learn about me, so

> Is it common / advisable to add my personal web site to my curriculum
>   vitae ?

Comment: See this other question, where he questions even including date of birth and marital status ... https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95510/why-is-personal-information-dob-marital-status-listed-on-cvs-in-europe-and-ca

Comment: @GEdgar I actually added my date of birth to my CV :)

Comment: Well, what's on your personal website? Anime reviews (just going off your profile picture) or a link to all your articles?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Sort of usual staff for the time being. Links to my accounts on some web sites (like github, researchgate etc.), my contact address, my photo, and link to my CV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a research oriented website, or even the website of your research group (where you are PI), it could be useful and won't do any harm. If it is your anime review website (see comment by @Azor-Ahai) the CV is probably the wrong place for it. That is, unless you apply for an anime related position.